# A generalization of Erdős–Mordell inequality

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometry, inequalities, plane-geometry

I proposed my conjecture [generalization of Erdős–Mordell inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Mordell_inequality) as following:

Let $A_1A_2....A_n$ be a polygon in a plane, $P$ be the point in $A_1A_2....A_n$. Let $d_i$ be the distances from $P$ to $A_iA_{i+1}$, for $i=1,...,n$ and $A_{i+1}=A_1$. Then:

$$\sum_{1}^{n}{ PA_i} \ge \frac{1}{cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}}\sum_{1}^{n}{d_i} $$

Equality holds when $A_1A_2....A_n$ be the regular polygon, and $P$ is its center.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a question here. What are you asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been proved here for convex polygons: Lenhard, H. C., Verallgemeinerung und Verschärfung der Erdös-Mordellschen Ungleichung für Polygone, Arch. Math. 12(1961), 311-314.

Comment: Thank to you, the same inequality (29) at here:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122107000600

But the inequality is true for $A_1A_2A_3....A_n$ don't need convex polygon.

Comment: There's also a weighted version: http://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/3.pdf